# About UTF-8(Uyghur) language support on Android 3.2 OS

Tags: android, utf-8, right-to-left

I found there are no RTF-8 and RTL language support on Android OS 3.2.
I use Sony tablet S, current system is Android 3.2
There are **10 million** Uyghur people are living in this world. 
but I fount Uyghur language and some Arabic fonts become very strange mark on this system.
If I use like "ROOT" to change system language , I may disable to continue SONY system guaranty.
So, is anyone can help with this problem?!
Is there any official support possibility for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional text support is a very popular feature request but it is not yet supported in the base platform.